# Simulating a Volleyball game in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, simulation

I want to simulate the following:

 We have two volleyball teams: 

 ‍‍‍‍‍‍ *‍‍L = the local one*  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍and ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ *V = the guests*

It is assumed that L has 18 points with the probability of p1=0.6 of scoring the next point whereas V has 20 points with the probability of p2=0.54 of scoring the next point.

What I've tried so far is this code:-

```
% Simulating a volleyball game

p1 = 0.6;  % Introducing the probabilities of both teams
p2 = 0.54;
n=25;      % The maximum number of points in a set

L=18;
V=20;

t1=(rand<p1);
t2=(rand<p2);

while n-L>0 || n-V>0

if t1==1
    L=L+1;
elseif t2==1
    V=V+1;

end
end 
disp([L V])
```

The thing is that it seems to have no end and I can't figure out a way of stopping the game when a team gets 25 points. Another issue is that I can't check the whether the loop is working correctly since the program doesn't display anything. I think the program is not calculating correct `t1` and `t2` , since it is doing it with the same random number.

 How to fix these things?

**Edit:**

 Also I want to run this 10,000 times and calculate winning percentage of each team!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the condition of the loop is incorrect. Second, there's a constant addition in the values of `t1` and `t2`  in every iteration. Third, there's nothing to counter the situation when both `t1` and `t2` are zero for which the loop will remain always true. Fourth, there's a mistake in assuming the probabilities because the sum of probabilities has to be equal to 1.

The modified code with corrections is as follows:

```
% The probabilities are incorrect but I'm leaving them as it is
p1 = 0.6;   
p2 = 0.54;
n = 25;     % The maximum number of points in a set

Result=zeros(1,1000);       % Pre-allocation

for k=1:1000
    L=18;
    V=20;

    while n-L>0 & n-V>0     % Notice the condition
        t1 = (rand<p1);
        t2 = (rand<p2);

        if t1==1
            L=L+1;
        elseif t2==1
            V=V+1;
        end
    end
    Result(k)=L>V ;         % Storing L's victories as 1 and V's victories as 0
end

Win_Percent_L = length(find(Result))/1000
Win_Percent_V = 1-Win_Percent_L
```

Comment: Right :)  and How can I make more simulations of this game (I mean reproduce this like 10000 times)?

Comment: jajajaa Yes jajaja right :) just a second please :)

Comment: @Sadar_Usama If I want to know the percentage of games that each team I have to sum all the occasions that V or L have 25 points and divide that by 10000 but how can I count that ?

Comment: Right, sorry but I thought this doesn't deserve it, but what I did is the following 
if L==n
    L1=[L];
    
end 
if V==n
    V1=[V];
    
end 
   but I think it didn't work

Comment: @Sadar_Usama   Why? jjajaja I know I did it wrong but Can you help me ?